# Sorting Cartesian coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, coordinate-transformation, coordinate

Here is the problem:

I create a coordinate list as follows:

```
DegreeP = 5;
lst = DeleteDuplicates@
       Select[Flatten[
        Table[Permutations[{a, b}], {a, 0, DegreeP}, {b, 0, DegreeP}],
              2], #[[1]] + #[[2]] <=DegreeP &];
```

By assigning the index of each coordinate, I can represent the order as a listplot

```
ListPlot[{lst, lst},
Joined -> {True, False}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Black}, 
ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20,
Epilog -> (n = 1; Text[Style[n++, 11], #, {-1, -1}] & /@ lst)]
```

[image]

The real order (solution) in which the coordinates should be found, however, is as follows

```
sol = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {0, 4}, 
      {4, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {0, 5}, {5, 0}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 4}, {4, 1}};
```

As a ListPlot

```
ListPlot[{sol, sol},
Joined -> {True, False}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Black}, 
ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20,
Epilog -> (n = 1; Text[Style[n++, 11], #, {-1, -1}] & /@ sol)]
```

[image]

I would like to find a way to sort my lst to get the same order as sol

For that, I tried with SortBy[] but I am unable to find the right pattern...

Any idea ?

*** UPDATE AFTER @kglr ANSWER***

```
DegreeP = 9;
lst = Join @@ Map[SortBy[{-Norm@# &}]@FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, #] &]@ Range[0, DegreeP];

ListPlot[{lst, lst}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
PlotStyle -> {Orange, Black}, ImageSize -> 600, 
PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, 
Epilog -> (n = 1; Text[Style[n++, 11], #, {-1, -1}] & /@ lst)]
```

Let's print the result for DegreeP={8,9,10}, it seems that there is a "jump" in the pattern for DegreeP = 9. This case does not seem to occur anymore for 20>DegreeP>1.

Note :

- I am only interested in DegreeP<20
- I cannot manually change the position of the elements

DegreeP = 8

[image]

DegreeP = 9

[image]

DegreeP = 10

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[f, shuffle]
shuffle = If[Length @ # <= 2, #, 
    Join[#[[{1, -1}]], 
      Take[Riffle[#, Reverse @ #], Length @ #] & @ Delete[#, {{1}, {-1}, {-2}}], 
      {#[[-2]]}]] &;

f[dp_] := Join @@ Map[shuffle @ FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, #] &] @ Range[0, dp];
```

***Examples:***

```
degreeP = 5;

ListPlot[{f[degreeP], f[degreeP]}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Black}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], 11], #, {-1, -1}]&, f[degreeP]]]
```

[image]

With `degreeP = 7` we get

[image]

and `degreeP = 9` gives

[image]

and `degreeP = 20` gives

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
degreeP = 5;

sol2 = Join @@ Map[SortBy[{- Norm @ # &}] @ 
   FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, #] &] @ Range[0, degreeP];

sol2 == sol
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
ListPlot[{sol2, sol2}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Black}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], 11], #, {-1, -1}] &, sol2]]
```

[image]

With `degreeP = 7` we get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works well for several DegreeP but there seems to be a problem with the patern for DegreeP = 7. It's a bit out of the scope of my question but do you think we could generalize that for DegreeP = N

Comment: @JocelynMinini, not sure what the correct ordering would be in general. Please try the new version.

Comment: I have updated the question I hope it is more clear

Comment: @JocelynMinini, please see the update.

Comment: It works perfectly. Elegant solution by the way

Answer (score 5):

```
sol = SortBy[lst, {(First@# + Last@#) &, Norm}]
```

The above solution was me looking at the display pattern you added to your post.

---

A little bit more MMA-esque:

```
sol = SortBy[lst, {Total@# &, Norm}]
```

---

and then realizing that Norm has an additional parameter:

```
sol = SortBy[lst, {Norm[#, 1] &, Norm[#, 2] &}]
```

OK done.